# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'banco_embozado_especial'

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

So here is the error:

```
2020-11-27 20:24:01.004 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-27 20:24:01.006  INFO 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-27 20:24:01.006  INFO 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2020-11-27 20:24:01.007 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@2c4ca0f9]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.013 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@4055fdc9]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.019 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@49a0e5b1]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.027 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@223a25c6]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.036 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@5cdd4520]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.037 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.037  INFO 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 31 ms
2020-11-27 20:24:01.037 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2020-11-27 20:24:01.049 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/home/v1/bank/getBanks]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.054 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /home/v1/bank/getBanks
2020-11-27 20:24:01.057 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.util.List<com.prisma.model.Bank> com.prisma.controller.BankController.getBanks()]
2020-11-27 20:24:01.058 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/home/v1/bank/getBanks] is: -1
2020-11-27 20:24:01.125  INFO 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2020-11-27 20:24:01.334  WARN 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2020-11-27 20:24:01.334 ERROR 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid object name 'banco_embozado_especial'.
2020-11-27 20:24:01.343 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<com.prisma.model.Bank> com.prisma.controller.BankController.getBanks()]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2020-11-27 20:24:01.346 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<com.prisma.model.Bank> com.prisma.controller.BankController.getBanks()]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2020-11-27 20:24:01.346 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<com.prisma.model.Bank> com.prisma.controller.BankController.getBanks()]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2020-11-27 20:24:01.357 DEBUG 29830 --- [nio-8164-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

the entity Bank

```
package com.prisma.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="BancoEmbozadoEspecial")
public class Bank {
    
    @Id
    private Integer bancoID;

    private String dDesde;

    private String dBaja;

    private String cUserUpdate;

    private String dupdate;

    private String formatoEmbozadoEspecial;
}
```

repository

```
package com.prisma.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.prisma.model.Bank;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface BankRepository extends JpaRepository<Bank,Integer> {
    Optional<Bank> findOneByBancoID(Integer BancoID);
    List<Bank> findAll();
    Bank save(Bank bank);
    void deleteById(Integer BancoID);
}
```

Service files

```
package com.prisma.service.impl;

import com.prisma.exception.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.prisma.model.Bank;
import com.prisma.repository.BankRepository;
import com.prisma.service.interfaces.IBankService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BankService implements IBankService {

    private BankRepository bankRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BankService(BankRepository bankRepository){
        this.bankRepository = bankRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Bank findByBancoID(Integer BancoID){
        return bankRepository.findOneByBancoID(BancoID).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("No se encontró el filtro con el código" + BancoID));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Bank> findAll() {
        return bankRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Bank save(Bank bank){
        return bankRepository.save(bank);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer BancoID) {
        bankRepository.deleteById(BancoID);
    }
}

package com.prisma.service.interfaces;

import com.prisma.model.Bank;

import java.util.List;

public interface IBankService {
    Bank findByBancoID(Integer BancoID);
    List<Bank> findAll();
    Bank save(Bank bank);
    void deleteById(Integer BancoID);
}
```

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prisma</groupId>
    <artifactId>sgp</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>sgp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.5.3</liquibase.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SSOClientPrisma</groupId>
            <artifactId>sso-client-prisma</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-external</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sso-client-prisma-1.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>SSOClientPrisma</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sso-client-prisma</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>p12</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pfx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pem</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-external</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sso-client-prisma-1.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>SSOClientPrisma</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sso-client-prisma</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                            <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>                        
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

and finally the application.properties

```
#Server Properties
server.port=8164

#Logging Properties
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.path=/opt/prisma/sg/sgp/backend/log

spring.profiles.active=dev,LoginMock
spring.main.banner-mode=off

#SSO
sso.url=http://172.16.0.221:26960/sso/services/SSOService

#Request Middlware
middleware.url=http://172.16.1.72:8463
middleware.endpoint.card.status=/lan/cards/getCardList
middleware.endpoint.card.status.detail=/lan/cards/getCardDetails

#Swagger
swagger.api.title=SGP - Backend
swagger.api.description=Webservice para retornar datos de la aplicacion SGP
swagger.api.version=1.0.0

#ABM Bancos

#DB Properties
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxSERVER21;databaseName=DB_xx_11062020
spring.datasource.username=xxusername
spring.datasource.password=xxpassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false

## envers
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true

## Bulk inserts and updates
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true

# Hikari
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SG-SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionInitSql=SELECT 1
```

I cannot find how it is mapping the name of the table and all that.

I tried adding some other naming strategies, but so far nothing worked.

My table is called BancoEmbozadoEspecial and it's mapped like banco_embozado_especial, so it doesn't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "My table is called BancoEmbozadoEspecial and it's mapped like banco_embozado_especial, so it doesn't find it."? Where are you providing this mapping? Just providing @Table(name="BancoEmbozadoEspecial") in entity class should suffice.

Comment: I thought the same, that setting this @Table(name="BancoEmbozadoEspecial") would suffice but I'm really lost

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file defining a `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` property? Sounds like you have a naming strategy implementing a snake_case convertor.

Comment: Can you check if banco_embozado_especial is specified anywhere in your code?